# My drawString won't work

Tags: java, string, object, drawstring

Im somewhat new in java, been programming for about a year now and im currently working on a project that lets the user choose a map (worldmap for example) and add cities to that map by clicking the map.

When the user clicks on the map he/she inputs a name and the city is drawn on those coordinates, and that work's fine. My problem is that I also want the name of the city to be drawn above the city, but I can't get it to work for some reason. 
It should be an easy task, but been trying for several hours now and it's starting to get very annoying so I hope someone else can help me with this simple enquiry.

The code:

```
public class Rita extends JComponent{
    private boolean klickad=false;
    protected int xx=0;
    private int yy=0;
    public Rita(int x, int y){
        xx=x;
        yy=y;
        setBounds(x, y, 20, 20);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
    }

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
        drawString(g, xx+5, yy);
        if(klickad==false)
            klickadVal(g, xx, yy);

        else if(klickad==true)
            oKlickadVal(g);
    }
public void drawString(Graphics g, int x, int y){
    setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Test test test test test", x, y);
}

public void klickadVal(Graphics g, int x, int y){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
}

public void oKlickadVal(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight());
```

Thanks in advance
/Jimmy

Comment: When you say that you "can't get it to work", are you getting any errors or anything like that?

Comment: How is it not working? Is the method being called? Is the string displaying at all?

Comment: Just a hint: `if(klickad==false) ... else if(klickad==true) ...` would better be `if(klickad==false) ... else ...` or yet better `if(!klickad) ... else ...` - `klickad` can only either be true or false :)

Comment: Not getting any error messages, and my rectangle is drawn on the map, but the string won't show. The drawString method is called (checked that with a println) but the string isn't drawn on the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your drawing coordinates should be define relative to the component.
You are setting the bounds of the component to `x,y,w,h` and drawing your text to the same `x` and `y`.
If `x > w` or `y > h`, then it won't be visible.

Change your code to this, using relative coordinates for the drawing commands:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
        drawString(g, 5, 10);
        if(klickad==false)
            klickadVal(g, 0, 0);

        else if(klickad==true)
            oKlickadVal(g);
}
```

And be aware of that your drawing area is only 20px*20px, because of your bounds width and height.

Comment: That worked. Thanks man! Wasn't realizing that when using this method, my string will be drawn inside the rectangle.
Suppose I will need another object only containing the drawString method with my x and y coordinates + a few pixles for it to be drawn ontop of the rectangle.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are calling klickadVal or oKlickadVal after you've painted the string.  These two methods fill the entire component with a single color overwriting the string you've displayed.

Comment: Thought about that earlier, so tried to remove the drawRect and only called drawString but that didn't work so that wasn't the problem. Thanks anyway for your input